# xml attribure in dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, dataset

I want to bind Repeater control to Dataset which is filled with XML data, but i don't know how to show attributes inside repeater.

Xml File:

```
<root>
   <items>
      <item id="9" name="111111111111" description="111111245" views="1"  galleryID="0" />
   </items>
</root>
```

Repeater code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrGalleries" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <a href='Page?id=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id") %>'><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name") %></a>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Codebehind:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/xml/gallery.xml"));

        IEnumerable<XElement> items = from item in doc.Descendants("item")
                                      orderby Convert.ToDateTime(item.Attribute("lastChanges").Value) descending
                    where int.Parse(item.Attribute("galleryID").Value) == 0 && bool.Parse(item.Attribute("visible").Value) != false
                    select item;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(new StringReader(doc.ToString()));

        rptrGalleries.DataSource = ds;
        rptrGalleries.DataBind();
```

When I compile site I receive this error:

```
System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'id'.
```

Comment: Although I have provided an alternate approach below, I believe the issue is with how you are building your dataset here.  Also, why do you even call the linq query to populate items, when you aren't using the results at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your repeater like so:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptTest" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptTest_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkTest" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Bind your repeater to the `IEnumerable<XElements>` items object.

```
   XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/xml/gallery.xml")); 
            IEnumerable<XElement> items = from item in doc.Descendants("item")
                                          orderby Convert.ToDateTime(item.Attribute("lastChanges").Value) descending
                                          where int.Parse(item.Attribute("galleryID").Value) == 0 && bool.Parse(item.Attribute("visible").Value) != false
                                          select item;

            rptTest.DataSource = items;
            rptTest.DataBind();
```

And then Bind the data OnItemDataBound in the code behind like this:

```
void rptTest_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    XElement item = (XElement)e.Item.DataItem;
    HyperLink lnkTest = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("lnkTest");
    lnkTest.NavigateUrl = "Page?id=" + item.Attribute("id").Value;
    lnkTest.Text = item.Attribute("name").Value;
}
```

This is just how I would do it.  I find that I have a lot more control in OnItemDataBound than trying to pass data directly to the ASP.Net Page.